# How do I pass an Asset Name (I selected) to a controller on a different page

Tags: apex-code, visualforce, force.com

I created a custom Page which loads a list of Assets.
I click on the Asset Name and now want to send the Asset name I clicked to my Controller so that I can do :

Asset myasset = SELECT name from Asset where name = [CLICKED ASSET NAME TEXT]

How do I pass that data to the controller.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VisualForce:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!theAssets}" var="asset">
  <apex:commandLink value="{!asset.Name}" action="{!someAction}">
    <apex:param name="paramName" assignTo="{!assetName}" value="{!asset.Name}" />
  </apex:commandLink>
</apex:repeat>
```

In the controller, make sure you define the property for the asset name:

```
public String AssetName { get; set; }
```

Elsewhere in the controller, you could have the statement:

```
Asset myasset = [SELECT name from Asset where name = :AssetName];
```

Comment: Jeremy, I am still a novice and I am not fully understanding the code above.
Why do I need the CommandLink> 
My page has one Asset called "Asset1" Can I not jyst get the Asset.Name and pass it as a variable?

Comment: The commandLink allows you to set the controller's AssetName property. I added another line of code to show how you could use that property in a SOQL query.

Comment: I still need a bit more direction like where I am getting the Values, etc

Comment: <apex:page Controller="callREST" id="thePage"  action="{!getData}">
  <apex:pageBlock title="Axeda Assets" >
     <apex:image id="theImage" value="{!$Resource.AxedaLogo}" width="210" height="62"/>
     <apex:enhancedList type="Asset" ...  />
     <apex:enhancedList type="Case"...  />
  </apex:pageBlock>
  <apex:form >
  <apex:repeat value="{!AssetName}" var="asset">
  <apex:commandLink value="AssetName">
    <apex:param name="paramName" assignTo="{!AssetName}" value="{!asset}" />
  </apex:commandLink>
  </apex:repeat>
  </apex:form>  
</apex:page>

Comment: If you're using an enhancedList to list the assets, it will send the user to the Asset's detail page, completely bypassing your controller. In my example, I used a repeat and the commandLink which keeps the user inside your controller. To populate the repeat, you'd have a property on the controller `public List<Asset> TheAssets { get; set; }`, which you need to populate with a list of assets before the page is rendered.

Comment: Jeremy, What I am doing is , I have a tab I created that shows Assets and Cases (enhanced list)
When I click on the asset, I am taken to the Asset Detail where I populate a field (a call in my Controller to an external server retrieves a value) then I update a field with that value.

The reason I need to pass the Actual Assets Name I clicked is because I will pass it in the http request URL 

I tried what you said and still do not have it working...

Comment: The call to the external server works fine and retrieves the value if I use: HARDCODED NAME OF ASSET

       Asset myAsset = [SELECT name FROM Asset WHERE name='First Asset'];
       myAsset.Firmware__c = resp.getValue('firmware').str;

Comment: Jeremy,
Can you still assist? I have hit a brick wall and I would really appreciate it.